# Return vs Print in functions using a list of lists

Tags: python

I'm having some unexpected results with trying to iterate through a list of lists using a function.

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

def list_of_lists(l):
    for i in l:
        return i

print list_of_lists(A)

Out : [1, 2, 3]
```

---

```
A = [[1,2,3],
     [4,5,6]]

def list_of_lists(l):
    for i in l:
        print i

print list_of_lists(A)

Out : [1, 2, 3]
      [4, 5, 6]
      None
```

Why does it seem like I'm only returning the first element of A when my function uses return?

Answer (score 1):

use `yield` instead of `return` if you want to "return" multiple values.
`return` exits the function at the first execution. `yield` can be used to return multiple values. The returned values are treated like a list